# Setting a page name depending on which view is active

Tags: angularjs

I have a single page application, where I have to display which view in ng-view is currently active.

Each view has its own controller so I presume they have to communicate somehow to change the value of a span.

So far I tried playing around with scopes and emit/broadcast but nothing really works.

Comment: why not use the url?

Comment: could you share some of the emit/broadcast code you tried to use?

Answer (score 0):

In angular, cross-controller communication is done using a Service with your "General" data like page title, subtitle, and such...

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$rootScope`. Add `$rootScope.page_name = 'View Name';` in each controller with respective *View Names*. Then bind the `page_name` to span.